# ?_wadl vs ?wsdl (underscore in parameter name)

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, cxf, wadl

I've been on Google for a while this morning, haven't found my answer so far. I have a single service which returns a WSDL when I request service?wsdl, and returns a WADL when I request service?_wadl.

**What is the convention re use of underscore when requesting the service's WSDL or WADL?** I notice that, under documentation for [JAX-RS Services Description](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-description.html#JAXRSServicesDescription-ServicelistingsandWADLqueries), they use the ?_wadl notation for every example. On the other hand, documentation pertaining to the use of WSDLs (usually in the context of a client making a request using CXF to open a WSDL file, to use as a service contract rather than in the context of generating/providing a WSDL to the 'outside world') refer to service?wsdl in the URLs.

Is it to do with whether the WSDL/WADL is auto-generated? **Is there a parameter which can be used to define the URL used to access the WSDL/WADL?** I'm using CXF 2.7.11.

Answer (score 0):

These (`?wsdl`, [`?singleWsdl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277536/what-is-the-difference-between-wsdl-and-singlewsdl-parameters/)) are all conventions that happen to be fallowed by everybody (I once tried to find out from where `?wsdl` originated from but was unable to find any information about it).

But just like what happened with WSDL2 (with WSDL1 still being the de facto way of describing SOAP web services), [people didn't rush to jump onto the WADL wagon](http://bitworking.org/news/193/Do-we-need-WADL). `_wadl` is probably another convention waiting to gain speed (I think they went for an underscore just because `wadl` and `wsdl` are easily confused, and easy to mistype, both keys being next to each other - but that's just my guess, I wasn't able to find out anything about this either).

And as a counter example, [Jersey has another convention](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/wadl.html), `/application.wadl`.

I'm not familiar with CXF but at first glance after downloading the source code, it doesn't look like you can change the way the WADL is retrieved or provide another URL to access it.