# How to consume a C# webservice from Java having only the wsdl

Tags: java, c#, web-services, wsdl

I'm new to webservices.
I have to develop a webservice client for a what seems a WCF webservice.
I have only the  [wsdl](http://184.13.69.115:7085/XOneGenericLoader/v2/mex?wsdl=wsdl0)
 but the problem is that the wsdl does not define any wsdl:service.

I 've already tried with wsdl2java but it gives me a warning

> WARNING: WSDL document http://184.13.69.115:7085/XOneGenericLoader/v2/mex?wsdl=wsdl0 does not define any services

The webservice also defines a binding like this :
`<wsdl:binding name="ExternalInterfaces-SOAP-Binding-Streaming_IXOneGenericLoaderService" type="tns:IXOneGenericLoaderService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>`
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch : have you tried using the `?singleWsdl` parameter ?

On my web service I have 2 interfaces :

This for svcutil.exe :

```
svcutil.exe http://localhost:8890/CalfitecECC/WsvcCalfitec.svc?wsdl
```

and this for full wsdl file :

```
http://localhost:8890/CalfitecECC/WsvcCalfitec.svc?singleWsdl
```

try `?wsdl` or `?singlewsdl` rather than `?wsdl=wsdl0`

Comment: no ..i have only this interface ...and it still do not helps if I would get another wsdl

Comment: have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277536/what-is-the-difference-between-wsdl-and-singlewsdl-parameters I don't get wsdl:service on mine with ?wsdl=wsdl0 but I get it with ?singleWsdl and with ?wsdl