# Asp.NET Core 2.2 WCF Warning: Policy

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core, policy, service-reference

I'm trying to add wsdl using WCF. But at first I get an warning like this;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBrPi.png)

**Here is the details:**

The following Policy Assertions were not Imported:

```
XPath://wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style']/wsdl:binding[@name='zz_binding_SOAP12']
```

Assertions:

```
<saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer xmlns:saptrnbnd='http://www.sap.com/webas/710/soap/features/transportbinding/'>..</saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer>
<sapattahnd:Enabled xmlns:sapattahnd='http://www.sap.com/710/features/attachment/'>..</sapattahnd:Enabled>
```

The following Policy Assertions were not Imported:

```
XPath://wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style']/wsdl:binding[@name='zz_binding']
```

Assertions:

```
    <saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer xmlns:saptrnbnd='http://www.sap.com/webas/710/soap/features/transportbinding/'>..</saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer>
    <sapattahnd:Enabled xmlns:sapattahnd='http://www.sap.com/710/features/attachment/'>..</sapattahnd:Enabled>
```

The optional WSDL extension element 'Policy' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy' was not handled.

```
XPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style']/wsdl:portType[@name='zz_test_web_structure']/wsdl:operation[@name='ZzTestWebService']
```

The optional WSDL extension element 'Policy' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy' was not handled.

```
XPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style']/wsdl:portType[@name='zz_test_web_structure']
```

I still can't run the wcf service after adding it. Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider` tool based on the `Mex` service endpoint, namely metadata exchange service endpoint instead of the `Web service definition language`(WSDL page).

```
  <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" bindingConfiguration="mybinding"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
</services>
```

Or,

```
Binding mexbinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding();
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), mexbinding, "mex");
```

If you prefer to generate a client proxy class by using WSDL, you could try the SVCUtil.exe tool.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe
All the above ways can generate a client proxy class.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client
Besides, In WCF4.5 there is a new feature called `SingleWSDL`, which contains the whole WSDL with the related schema. It could be consumed perfectly by a third-party system.
[What is the difference between ?wsdl and ?singleWsdl parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277536/what-is-the-difference-between-wsdl-and-singlewsdl-parameters)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-new
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.