# Error: Invalid WSDL URL, seems like "?wsdl" is being replaced by "xsd=xsd1"

Tags: node.js, soap, xsd, wsdl, bing

I'm using a node soap client to connect to the Bing Ads API and I log the URL within the sendRequest() method:

`https://clientcenter.api.bingads.microsoft.com/Api/CustomerManagement/v13/CustomerManagementService.svc?wsdl`

[Which is correct according to the Bing docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/web-service-addresses?view=bingads-13#customer).

But when I get the error output (after the code hangs) it's a different URL. The entire error is:

`Error: Invalid WSDL URL: https://clientcenter.api.bingads.microsoft.com/Api/CustomerManagement/v13/CustomerManagementService.svc?xsd=xsd1`

Side by side of the two URLs:

`https://clientcenter.api.bingads.microsoft.com/Api/CustomerManagement/v13/CustomerManagementService.svc?wsdl`

`https://clientcenter.api.bingads.microsoft.com/Api/CustomerManagement/v13/CustomerManagementService.svc?xsd=xsd1`

It looks like the only difference is that `wsdl` in the correct URL is being replaced by `xsd=xsd1`.

Also, I know very little about SOAP APIs so I'm just trying to figure out what is happening.

Why is the URL being altered?

Comment: It's most likely an import within the WSDL that is not working. You may find this explanation useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277536/what-is-the-difference-between-wsdl-and-singlewsdl-parameters. Download the WSDL file and look inside it. In the types section of the WSDL you should find an import to that url with xsd=xsd1. That's what's failing... most likely.